# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $message ]]

Tags: php, laravel, components

I'm trying to have a message pop up on the browser once they edit an item of inventory on my edit.blade.php file. I have the router, controller, and view file connected so I am able to edit an item of inventory and see the changes on the browser but my message saying you successfully edited the inventory doesn't show.
Here is my InventoryForm.php component form:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class InventoryForm extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var Inventory|null
     */
    public $inventory;

    /**
     * Successfully edited message
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * @param Inventory|null $inventory
     *
     * @param string $message
     */
    public function __construct(Inventory $inventory = null, string $message)
    {
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.inventory-form');
    }
}
```

Here is my edit.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Create Inventory')

@section('menu')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Edit {{ $inventory->title }}</strong></h1>
    <x-inventory-form :inventory=$inventory/>
@endsection
```

When I hover over (Inventory $inventory = null) next to my constructor it also says "Optional parameter is provided before required."

When I try and edit an item of inventory I get this error:

Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string $message ]] in class App\View\Components\InventoryForm (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/pages/inventories/edit.blade.php)

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

in `<x-inventory-form>` tags the :message attribute is required. So in order to fix this you can:

1. Add default to the constructor parameter in your InvetoryForm.php so message attribute is not re

`public function __construct(Inventory $inventory = null, string $message = null)`

2. Add the attribute in your blade file
   `<x-inventory-form :inventory="$inventory" :message="$message">`
   or pass it to string with:
   `<x-inventory-form :inventory="$inventory" message="some massage">`

Reference can be found at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components

Answer (score 0):

```php
 public function __construct(Inventory | null $inventory = null, string $message)
 {
     $this->inventory = $inventory;
     $this->message = $message;
 }


You are just accepting Inventory Class and not `null` in the function use Inventory | null to make this possible
```